# How does the "needsCompositing" bit work?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to better understand how the Flutter framework interprets the "needsCompositing" / "alwaysNeedsCompositing" bits.

When the needsCompositing bit is set on a render object, does *every single* ancestor render object up to the nearest repaint boundary also need compositing (i.e., its own composited layer)? Is this because any of those objects might, say, add a clip which may affect the newly composited child and in order to ensure that it does, a clip *layer* has to be used instead?

The part that seems surprising is that this would appear to add N new layers for N render objects just because one descendant needs compositing.

If this is true, I suppose this explains why you'd want to organize things into a shallow "repaint boundary sandwich."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`needsCompositing` is just going to signal to the render object whether it should be pushing a layer or not, which may or may not be true depending on what properties are set on the object. `alwaysNeedsCompositing` is unconditionally saying that.

It has no effect on ancestors - they can independently need or not need compositing, which again will control how the layer tree is constructed so that composition will happen on the engine side.

On an update, we do pump logic up the tree to make sure things get properly marked dirty (up to the nearest `RepaintBoundary`).  However, individual render objects may respond to that by only pumping the data further up the tree and not setting their `needsCompositing` to true, if they never actually need compositing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The thing that confuses me is [this process](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart#L1948).

That is, updating the bits in one render object seems to cause [ancestor render objects to be updated, as well](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart#L1984).


This is alluded to in the docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject/needsCompositing.html).

Does this mean all ancestor render objects will subsequently get their own layers?

Comment: That's just signaling that compositing bits should be considered dirty - a specific implementation may never set them, dirty or not.